# Proper Inheritance Design

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have three classes named A, B, and C. B inherits from A and C inherits from B. (A -> B -> C).

I also have an abstract base class named IBinary. I'd like to make all of the classes implement the IBinary interface. When I make class A inherit from IBinary, the output of my code is `C::readb`. When class A does not inherit from IBinary, the output is `B:readb`.

What is the proper way to make my three classes subscribe to the same interface? If I only have the top class (A) inherit from the interface class, I'll need to refactor my code so that I don't have resolution problems like the one above.

If I explicitly have all of the classes inherit from the interface class then I'll have a more complicated class hierarchy and become closer to having a diamond of death.

---

```
#include <iostream>

class IBinary {
public:
    virtual void readb( std::istream& in ) = 0;
};

// Basic A -- change whether this inherits from IBinary
class A : public IBinary {
public:
    A() {};

    void readb( std::istream& in ) {}
};

// Specialized A
class B : public A {
public:
    B() {};

    void load() {
        this->readb(std::cin);        // <-- which readb is called?
    }
    void readb( std::istream& in ) {
        std::cout << "B::readb" << std::endl;
    }
};

// Specialized B
class C : public B {
public:
    C() {};

    void readb( std::istream& in ) {
        std::cout << "C::readb" << std::endl;
    }
    void foo() {
        B::load();
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.foo();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What do you *want* `c.foo` to do?

Comment: What does it mean for a class to subscribe to an interface?

Comment: @Casey I'm using subscribe to mean implement. I guess implement is more clear.

Comment: @Derek: That doesn't answer the question. What do you want the result of the function call to be?

Comment: @NicolBolas The original code should call `B::readb`.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly - you want to enforce all derived classes to implent `readB` but you don't want virtual calls to it?

Comment: @jrok *I* want to support virtual calls. I'm coming to understand that the code wasn't designed expecting virtual calls.

Comment: Odd. Well, one option is to qualify the calls when you don't want dynamic dispatch, `A::readb`, `B::readb`, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `virtual` in the definition of `IBinary::readb` makes all the difference.

When you inherit from `IBinary`, all the `readb`s in the hierarchy that override the one from `IBinary` are implicitly virtual, too. So virtual dispacth kicks in, just as it's supposed to.

When you don't, then the call is resolved statically. Because the call is inside `B`, it is `B::readb` that gets called.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going with the code just wasn't designed with virtual dispatch in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Just have `A` inherit from `IBinary` which will make all the children be usable as the abstract interface `IBinary`.

Comment: So the line `this->readb(std::cin);` would have to become `this->B::readb(std::cin);`?

Comment: @Derek Why do you want to call `B::readb` when you've explicitly said it should be virtual and decided at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is, in short, because `A::readb` is not declared `virtual`.

Because `IBinary::readb` is `virtual`, when `A` inherits from it, `A::readb` becomes `virtual` by default.

Your code would behave more consistently if you added `virtual` to every declaration of `readb`, rather than just the first. For this reason, a lot of code style guides for C++ make it a requirement that all `virtual` methods be declared `virtual` in all derived classes, even if they are not the ancestor base class.

Comment: Adding virtual to all `readb`s wouldn't make any difference. Removing it from `IBinary::readb` would.